# Is there a simple way to tell if json object contains a property?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to know if a property exists in a json tree, no matter in what depth.

isPropertyExists(@JSON@,@property name@)// that returns [@is exists@,@property value@,@property path@]

example:

```
var jsonObj={
             lvl1a:{
                   lvl2a:{lvl3:"some value"},
                   lvl2b:{lvl3a:"some value",
                          lvl3b:"some value"}
                   },
             lvl1b:{
                   lvl2aa:"some value",
                   lvl2bb:{target1:"some value"}
                   }    
             }  
isPropertyExists(jsonObj,'lvl1a') // returns [true,jsonObj.lvl1a,'jsonObj.lvl1a']  
isPropertyExists(jsonObj,'target1') // returns [true,jsonObj.lvl1b.lvl2bb.target1,'jsonObj.lvl1b.lvl2bb.target1'] 
isPropertyExists(jsonObj,'target2') // returns false
```

Comment: It's a JavaScript object, not a JSON object.

Comment: Recursion is your friend

Comment: With JSON it's actually easier, you can just look for the string: `json.indexOf('"lvl1a":') != -1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution without path:

```
function hasProp(obj, prop) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        if (key === prop) {
            return [true, obj[key]];
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            hasProp(obj[key], prop);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Your function does not return a value, only your closure does.

Answer (score 1):

This is done using simple recursion.

Use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (rather than [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) or a [for..in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) because the latter two will iterate properties in the prototype chain).

**The solution**

Iterate over the enumerable properties of your object. If any of the property names match the name we're searching for, return true. Otherwise, if the property's value is another object, iterate over that one too.

**An example method**

```
function propertyExists(name, o) {
  var properties = Object.keys(o);
  for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    var property = properties[i];
    if (property === name)
      return true;
    if (typeof o[property] === 'object' && propertyExists(o[property], name))
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to implement a recursively function this will call itself

```
 function isPropertyExists (Json,findPropertyName,rootName) {
            var found = false;
            rootName+='->';
            for(iPropertyName in Json){
                  var iPropertyObject = Json[iPropertyName];                  
                  rootName+=iPropertyName;

                  console.log(rootName);
                  if(iPropertyName == findPropertyName){
                        console.log('-Exist!');
                        found = true;
                        break;                        
                  } else{     
                          //===>If is an object is because could contains a nested Json
                          if(typeof iPropertyObject =='object' ){
                             //===>Call itself and if return true will exit from the for loop an return true
                            if(isPropertyExists(iPropertyObject,findPropertyName,rootName)){
                              found = true;
                              break;
                            }
                          }  
                  }
                  rootName+='->';

            }
      return found;
      }

      console.log('End Result:',isPropertyExists(jsonObj,'target1','Root'));
```